# Event hub does not load in Azure portal when resource group has accent in its name

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

When I follow these steps:

1. create event hub in a namespace with a resource group named tést (or other name with é in it)
2. Try to open up the event hub in the portal

Then the portal never finishes loading the event hub and I get this:
[rainy cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KksQy.png)

I can reproduce this bug on different Azure subscriptions...

Comment: You should open a support ticket

Answer (score 0):

@SQLWaldorf,

I checked on this issue, when using the accent in Portal, it doesn't allow me to create the namespace since the character doesn't seem to be supported, I attached both screenshots from my experiment:

[image: With ACCENT]

**Then without accent:**
[image]